# Excel | Empty an column field if one has a value

Tags: excel, ms-office

I'm stuck with a function that needs to empty a field when one is being typed in.

Something like:

```
IF = (D3>0,F3.Set(null), F3=F3)
```

I have been looking for ages but haven't found something usefull

Comment: Are you putting this in F3 or a different cell?  If in a different cell, a function cannot change the value of a different cell than the one in which it is placed.  If in the same cell then you need to enable iterative calculations as this will be a circular reference, then your formula would be: `=IF(D3>0,"",F3)`

Comment: But now that I think of it F3 would always be blank then and never change.  So I do not think it is possible to do what you want outside of vba in a Worksheet_Change or Worksheet_Calculate event.

Comment: I want to put this in D3, let's assume that F column has data already

Comment: Then no you cannot do this without vba.

Comment: Oh really? It's my intro in Excel actually and I was told that Excel is a powerfull tool hehe. Would you mind motivating why this only would work with VBA?

Comment: It is a powerful tool if used correctly,  Could you imagine trying to track down what was changing a value if the formula doing so was somewhere on multiple pages, there are nearly 17 billion cells per sheet?  This inability to change the value of one cell value from another cell's formula saves a lot of headache and error.  And as I stated the method that is provided is vba, this way it is in one place and easily found and fixed when an error occurs.  Then there is the whole circular issue.  If A1 change A2 and A2 changes A1 it would circle till Excel crashes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will read myself into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give a cell this custom format, `[<>0]"";;` it will appear blank whatever *number* you enter. It doesn't work for text. For that you need the format `;;;` which will hide anything you enter. However, you must remember that you deal with Excel which rarely shows to you what there actually is in a cell. Therefore, when you enter a number or text in a cell formatted as above the cell will hold that number or text even while it shows a blank.

The reason why you need VBA to set a cell to a particular value is that there are only two sources of input, the user and someone (something) else. If the user inputs something that something will be in the cell. The cell's format will determine how to display that something but the user has determined what it is.

If you don't want to let the user determine a cell's content you must let code do it. The most available code for Excel is VBA. You can make a condition to write something in F3 that relates to D3. But the action of writing must be executed either by the user or by the code.

There is no normal worksheet formula that can write in any cell other than the one in which it resides, and when the user writes in that cell then the formula is gone, over-written by the user's input.

There are array formulas which have the capability of replicating themselves in many cells, thereby giving the appearance of writing in other cells, but that isn't a subject for Excel novices, nor could it offer a solution to your problem.

Comment: very well said :)